# Problem with Greengrass deployment from EC2 deployment

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-greengrass

I have been trying to deploy my first hello world AWS greengrass program, following AWS Greengrass documentation.

I have been using AWS EC2 (Amazon Linux) to deploy GG core device. As a first step, I have create one GG core device AWS IoT core and then configure it with AWS EC2. Everything works well!!

As a next step, I have used `hello world` GG code to deploy component from AWS EC2 to GG.
The recipe code as follow.

```
{
  "RecipeFormatVersion": "2020-01-25",
  "ComponentName": "com.example.HelloWorld",
  "ComponentVersion": "1.0.0",
  "ComponentDescription": "My first AWS IoT Greengrass component.",
  "ComponentPublisher": "Amazon",
  "ComponentConfiguration": {
    "DefaultConfiguration": {
      "Message": "world"
    }
  },
  "Manifests": [
    {
      "Platform": {
        "os": "linux"
      },
      "Lifecycle": {
        "Run": "python3 -u {artifacts:path}/hello_world.py \"{configuration:/Message}\""
      }
    },
    {
      "Platform": {
        "os": "windows"
      },
      "Lifecycle": {
        "Run": "py -3 -u {artifacts:path}/hello_world.py \"{configuration:/Message}\""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And the artifact code is as follow

```
import sys

message = "Hello, %s!" % sys.argv[1]

# Print the message to stdout, which Greengrass saves in a log file.
print(message)
```

I have used the following command to deploy this code.

```
sudo /greengrass/v2/bin/greengrass-cli deployment create \
  --recipeDir ~/greengrassv2/recipes \
  --artifactDir ~/greengrassv2/artifacts \
  --merge "com.example.HelloWorld=1.0.0"
```

When I run the above command, the following error is shown.

```
Sep 01, 2022 4:52:46 AM software.amazon.awssdk.eventstreamrpc.EventStreamRPCConnection$1 onConnectionSetup
INFO: Socket connection /greengrass/v2/ipc.socket:8033 to server result [AWS_ERROR_SUCCESS]
Sep 01, 2022 4:52:46 AM software.amazon.awssdk.eventstreamrpc.EventStreamRPCConnection$1 onProtocolMessage
INFO: Connection established with event stream RPC server
Local deployment submitted! Deployment Id: 2f6cc9cd-7f9d-49ce-ae61-bde9efe34aa5
```

The `greengrass.log` shows the following :

```
2022-09-01T04:52:49.965Z [INFO] (Copier) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: Run script exited. {exitCode=1, serviceName=com.example.HelloWorld, currentState=RUNNING}
2022-09-01T04:52:49.965Z [INFO] (com.example.HelloWorld-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: service-set-state. {serviceName=com.example.HelloWorld, currentState=RUNNING, newState=BROKEN}
2022-09-01T04:52:49.965Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-53) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: Shutdown initiated. {serviceName=com.example.HelloWorld, currentState=BROKEN}
2022-09-01T04:52:49.965Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-53) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: generic-service-shutdown. {serviceName=com.example.HelloWorld, currentState=BROKEN}
2022-09-01T04:52:50.895Z [WARN] (pool-2-thread-52) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentConfigMerger: merge-config. merge-config-service BROKEN. {serviceName=com.example.HelloWorld}
2022-09-01T04:52:50.895Z [ERROR] (pool-2-thread-52) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.activator.DeploymentActivator: merge-config. Deployment failed. {deploymentId=2f6cc9cd-7f9d-49ce-ae61-bde9efe34aa5}
com.aws.greengrass.deployment.exceptions.ServiceUpdateException: Service com.example.HelloWorld in broken state after deployment
    at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentConfigMerger.waitForServicesToStart(DeploymentConfigMerger.java:194)
    at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.activator.DefaultActivator.activate(DefaultActivator.java:84)
    at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentConfigMerger.updateActionForDeployment(DeploymentConfigMerger.java:150)
    at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentConfigMerger.mergeInNewConfig(DeploymentConfigMerger.java:107)
    at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DefaultDeploymentTask.call(DefaultDeploymentTask.java:155)
    at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DefaultDeploymentTask.call(DefaultDeploymentTask.java:50)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

2022-09-01T04:52:50.895Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-52) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentService: deployment-task-execution. Finished deployment task. {deploymentId=2f6cc9cd-7f9d-49ce-ae61-bde9efe34aa5, serviceName=DeploymentService, currentState=RUNNING}
2022-09-01T04:53:04.382Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-8) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentService: Current deployment finished. {DeploymentId=2f6cc9cd-7f9d-49ce-ae61-bde9efe34aa5, serviceName=DeploymentService, currentState=RUNNING}
2022-09-01T04:53:04.409Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-8) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentStatusKeeper: Stored deployment status. {DeploymentId=2f6cc9cd-7f9d-49ce-ae61-bde9efe34aa5, DeploymentStatus=FAILED}
2022-09-01T04:53:04.419Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-8) com.aws.greengrass.status.FleetStatusService: fss-status-update-published. Status update published to FSS. {trigger=LOCAL_DEPLOYMENT, serviceName=FleetStatusService, currentState=RUNNING}
2022-09-01T04:53:04.419Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-8) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentDirectoryManager: Persist link to last deployment. {link=/greengrass/v2/deployments/previous-failure}
2022-09-01T04:53:04.420Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-8) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentDirectoryManager: Clean up link to earlier deployment. {link=/greengrass/v2/deployments/previous-failure}
```

Cloud you please suggest how I could address this error?

Answer (score 0):

if there is a `/greengrass/v2/logs/com.example.HelloWorld.log` you can check if it contains additional information about the component failing to run.

If there is no such file, double-check that the layout of the directories from which you do the local publish is correct. Specifically, the `artifacts` folder should contain the following `artifacts/com.example.HelloWorld/1.0.0/hello_world.py`